# Не запускается приложение Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Сделал приложение, собрал все DLL , запустил у себя на пк, все работает, запустил на пк все работает, затем скинул другу , у него пишет что нету Qt5Core.dll , когда оно есть в папке

Скрин пк друга:
http://prnt.sc/t8i4zi

Comment: Как вы собирали? Какая конкретно ошибка? Приведите всё это в вопросе с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1147018/edit).

Comment: Сделал, добавил

Comment: Добавьте путь к директории с библиотекой(ами) в переменную окружения `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы гарантированно положить в папку с приложением все нужные запчасти от `Qt`, [используйте утилиту windeployqt](https://habr.com/ru/post/262211/) из состава `Qt`

Нужно при помощи `CMD` или `Powershell` дотопать до папки, где лежит релизный `exe` программы и вызвать утилиту, указав полный путь к ее исполняемому файлу.

Если же это не работает, возможно, вы забыли установить на целевую машину Visual Studio Redist от вашей версии Visual Studio

Comment: Я так и сделал, но вот такая ошибка

Comment: Вы в Visual Studio пишете?

Comment: В qt , или про что вы?

Comment: @DockedFerret800, все правильно написал, просто настройтесь ... Допустим у вас есть сборка Qt от Вижуал Студии и она лежит тут `C:\Tools\Qt5` - сделайте командный файл, и добавьте в переменную окружения PATH путь "C:\Tools\Qt5\5.14.1\msvc2017\bin\". Типа `SET PATH =C:\Tools\Qt5\5.14.1\msvc2017\bin;%PATH%`. Потом в командном файле вызывайте деплой по типу `C:\Tools\Qt5\5.14.1\msvc2017\bin\windeployqt.exe --dir ./deploy C:\Projects\c++\.Builds\build-UsbTestWatcher-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MSVC2017_32bit-Release\release\UsbTestWatcher.exe` (ну понятно где что?).

Comment: windeploy иногда не переносит сам exe-шник ... руками перенесите.

Answer (score 1):

Как ответ, я ответил в комментах. Но есть более другое предложение - **прекрасная статическая линковка** (соблюдение лицензионных соглашений на вашей совести)...

1. Развертываете Linux на виртуальной машине (если вы под виндо)
2. Заходите на сайт `http://mxe.cc` и внимательно читаете ВСЕ!
3. Создаете каталог /home/(ваш-юзернейм)/dev/cross
4. Заходите в него и выполняете `git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git`
5. Ставите зависимые либы

Для дебиана это:

```
apt-get install \
autoconf \
automake \
autopoint \
bash \
bison \
bzip2 \
flex \
g++ \
g++-multilib \
gettext \
git \
gperf \
intltool \
libc6-dev-i386 \
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev \
libltdl-dev \
libssl-dev \
libtool-bin \
libxml-parser-perl \
lzip \
make \
openssl \
p7zip-full \
patch \
perl \
python \
ruby \
sed \
unzip \
wget \
```

Ну а потом - сама установка 8 комплектов:

```
cd mxe
make MXE_TARGETS='i686-w64-mingw32.shared \
                  i686-w64-mingw32.static \
                  x86_64-w64- mingw32.static \                
                  x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared \
                  i686-w64-mingw32.shared.posix \
                  i686-w64-mingw32.static.posix \
                  x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix \
                  x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared.posix' \
xz postgresql libmysqlclient luajit qt5 -j2 JOBS=2
```

После этого ставишь штатный Qt5-Linux, valgring из пакетов, прописываешь ранее установленные компиляторы и пакеты Qt5 в настройках QtCreator'а.

Вот и все - у тебя альтернативное окружение разработки.
И САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ - могущее твою разработку линковать статически!
А это значит - **никаких деплоев, только твой исполняемый файл**.

ЗЫ: Перед отдачей исполняемого модуля заказчику - не забывай его стрипать(да и все dll-ки на всякий случай)! Ибо Qt и без того - жЫрная скотина.